Google reCAPTCHA v3 is always returning a score of 0.9
I have implemented Google reCAPTCHA v3 in my application. After publishing, I tested it with bots using developer tools, but it consistently returns a score of 0.9.
 var values = new Dictionary<string,string> { { "secret", secret }, { "response", response } }; var content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(values); var Response = hc.PostAsync("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", content).Result;
I tried with bots from developer tools , always getting score of 0.9
I also tested it with Selenium, and after 20-25 clicks, the score drops below 0.5.
